# selector back button history web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Would need to know the selector button to return to the previous page, for jquery or javascript.
to be understood would be something like:

```
('back-button').click(function(){

});
```

I want this and I need that when you click back to return to the home of my web.
Thank you very much

Comment: Not possible. The back button is part of the browser, not part of the web page. The best you can do is handle the `onbeforeunload` event and ask the user if they want to stay on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button id="back-button">Go Back</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#back-button').click(function(){
      window.history.back();//go back one page
});
```

Other possibilities:

```
window.location.history.go(-1);//go back one page
window.history.back();//go back one page
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //go to google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about as clear as mud, but I think he is either after this:

```
('#back-button').click(function(){
    location.href = "/urlofyourhomepage/";
});
```

Or this:

```
('#back-button').click(function(){
    window.history.back()
});
```

With a button being on the page with an ID of back-button.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="back-button">Go Back</a>
```

I don't (or at least I hope not) think that he wanted to intercept the back button functionality of the browser.